# Set lock timeout programmatically Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have

```
@Transactional(timeout = 600)
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public void actOnCustomer(Long customerId) {
    ...
```

along with

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Optional<Customer> findById(Long id);
```

The customer row seems to be getting locked, and the timeout value seems to be having the proper effect.

*Now I want to be able to set the timeout value programmatically, and/or using my application.properties file*.  I've seen some examples of setting `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` in properties passed to an `EntityManager`'s `find` method, but I'm not sure of how best to incorporate `EntityManager` calls into a Spring repository, and it seems like there should be a more Spring-y way (like setting `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.lock.timeout=600` in application.properties, which doesn't seem to work).

So how do I do this?

Comment: You can modify the TransactionDefinition timeout to be X seconds. Something like this, for example. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/spring-transaction-management-example-with-jdbc-example/ Then you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` or a setter or a bean with your own service.

Comment: @Compass Thanks.  This led me to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@PostConstruct
public void configureJpaTransactionManager() {
    ((JpaTransactionManager) this.platformTransactionManager).setDefaultTimeout(
                Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("transaction.timeout", "3")));
}
```

to my `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated main class, which seemed to do the job.  Not sure it is the best way.  ("transaction.timeout" is a property name I made up).